# Relationship between fps and time stamps

Tags: video-processing

I am getting a bit confused about fps (frame rate) in a video.

I build a video (using python and opencv) using 600 frames and I specify 10 fps.

However I want to also record the timestamps for each frame in a text file.
If the time for the first frame is 0 ns what would be the time stamp for the second frame provided the values I gave above?

EDIT:

About my confusion. If we have 10 frames with 0.1 difference we have

```
|     |   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
0   0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9
```

As you can see the time for the 10 frames is not one second but less so fps would not be 10 fps

```
|      |     |     |    |     |     |    |     |    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
0   0.11  0.22  0.33  0.44  0.56  0.67  0.78  0.89  1
```

Wouldn't this be the correct calculation?

Comment: Given the frame-rate FPS, then the duration between the frames is: $\Delta T = 1/FPS$  and the n-th frame is at time $t_n = (n-1)*\Delta T$, where $n = 1,2,...,N$ having $N = 600$ total frames

Comment: I get very confused by this. Shouldn't it be 1/(FPS-1)? Because if not the N frames will have a difference less than FPS

Comment: For your convenience, if you have 10 frames at 10 FPS, then the 10th frame will be at: $t_{10} = (n-1) \times \Delta T =  (10-1) \times (1/10) = 0.9 $ s, where $\Delta T = 1/FPS = 1/10 = 0.1 s$.. And if there would be any 11th frame, it would be at 1.0 s... So if there are N frames in the interval [ 0 , T ] s , then your frame rate is FPS = (N-1)/T . (your first figure is correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python implementation:

```
import numpy as np

frames = 600
# frames per seconds
fps = 10 
# sampling time in seconds
t_s = np.arange(600) / fps
# sampling time in nano-seconds
t_ns = t_s * (10**9)
```

Regarding the confusion related to the duration, the problem is that the sampling does not start at $t=0$, where the first sample takes place. If you consider that the sampling starts at $t=-\frac{1}{F_s}$ then it would all make sense.

Please do not neglect the integration time, which is part of the sampling process. For example, in the attached figure the sampling starts at $t=0$ but the first sample is at $t=\frac{1}{F_s}$.
[image]

Comment: that `600` should be `frames` right? (in `t_s` calculation)

Comment: I run this script. My only doubt is that if I substact `t_ns[599]` from `t_ns[0]` it gives me 59900000000.0 which divided by 10**9 gives me 59.9.  Shouldn't it be 60?